# parsing single text items from xml with Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, text, elementtree

I have been attempting to pull out a specific text item from a particular child of an element in my xml file. See XML below.

```
    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
        <Key>ConnectionFile</Key>
        <Value xsi:type="xs:string">THE TEXT I WANT, IN THIS CASE A FILE PATH</Value>
    </PropertySetProperty>
```

The problem is, there are approximately 8 different 'propertysetproperty' elements..... the keys are the unique part. How can I extract the text in Value, based on the key right above it? I.e. how can I code where key = ConnectionFile, print value right below it?

Thus far, I have tried the `xml.etree` and `xml.dom` with no success. Can someone point me in the right direction for pulling out the specific line of text - the file path?

I have been able to pull out values of unique items, such as the ClientHostName value mentioned in my script, but I'm struggling in how to properly call out the file path I need, since it is nested in the middle of so many similar elements/children (sorry I am a little rough on the xml terminology.)

```
import xml.etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '//xmlfile'

tree = ET.parse(xml)
root = tree.getroot()

for origin in root.iter('ClientHostName'):
    print origin.text
```

This code gives me exactly what I want - the client computer name. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated on pulling out the filepath.

Comment: So you want to find out text from `Value` element if it is inside of `PropertySetProperty` which has `Key` element with text `"ConnectionFile"`. Right?

Comment: Yes - or identify that exact line, ie if "for user in root.iter('value'): print user.text"    returns me 7 lines, i want to isolate the 5th one, for example.. I have grabbed single items out of a dictionary or tuple before, but I cannot use the same methods ehre for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xmlstr = """
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RootElement>
  <PropertySetProperty>
    <Key>KeyNotOfInterest</Key>
    <Value>ValueNotOfInterest</Value>
  </PropertySetProperty>
  <PropertySetProperty>
    <Key>ConnectionFile</Key>
    <Value>THE TEXT I WANT, IN THIS CASE A FILE PATH</Value>
  </PropertySetProperty>
  <PropertySetProperty>
    <Key>KeyAlsoNotOfInterest</Key>
    <Value>ValueAlsoNotOfInterest</Value>
  </PropertySetProperty>
</RootElement>
"""
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.fromstring(xmlstr.strip())
#doc = etree.parse("xmlfilename.xml")

xp = "//PropertySetProperty[Key/text()='ConnectionFile']/Value/text()"
wanted = doc.xpath(xp)[0]
print wanted
```

or possibly using xpath with a parameter:

```
xp = "//PropertySetProperty[Key/text()=$key]/Value/text()"
wanted = doc.xpath(xp, key="ConnectionFile")[0]
```

The XPath translates to:
"find element PropertSetProperty anywhere in the document, having subelement Key with text value being 'ConnectionFile', and get text value of Value subelement."

This assumes, you have `lxml` installed:

```
$ pip install lxml
```

On windows better use:

```
$ easy_install lxml
```

as it will install from downloaded exe installer and will not try to compile from sources.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using xml as a string (reading it straight from file instead?) I will be running a script that accesses an xml file in dozens of different directories..

Comment: @Strider Do you see the commented line? Uncomment it and comment out the previous one and you have it read from file. Of course, the `xmlstr=` part can be removed too. But the import `from lxml import etree` is essential.